# Has Anyone managed to get the PowerShell Interactive Windows Working in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Has anyone managed to get the PowerShell Interactive Window working in VS 2017 ?
I have tried CNTRL + SHIFT + \ but nothing happened.

Comment: The PowerShell debugger in Visual Studio Code is pretty solid.  You just need the PowerShell extension.